# Yii 2, Submit form using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii, yii2

I'm new to Yii and would appreciate any help. 
I render the view with form:

```
public function actionCreate()
{    
     return $this->render('create');       
}
```

view:

```
<form id="myform" action="/test/web/index.php?r=form/preorder" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="form-firstname" name="Form[firstName]" required maxlength="50">                    
    <input type="text" id="form-lastname" name="Form[lastName]" required maxlength="50">
    <input name="send" type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Im using plain html instead of Yii extensions in form, because I need to have a frontend with html/javascript only. On backend I can use Yii.

Now, I try to submit the form using ajax:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){      
$("body").on('beforeSubmit', 'form#myform', function(e){       
      var form = $(this);
      $.ajax({
            url    : form.attr('action'),
            type   : 'POST',
            data   : form.serialize(),
            success: function (response) 
            {                  
               console.log(response);
            },
            error  : function () 
            {
                console.log('internal server error');
            }
        });
    return false;

  });
});
```

FormController:

```
public function actionPreorder(){

     if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            $res = array(
                'body'    => $_POST,
                'success' => true,
            );
            //also I need to save to db
            return $res;
     }
}
```

The problem is when I submit the form, it redirects to the new page `preorder`, and I can't see my posted data. Im not sure what Im doing wrong.

Comment: Please specify why you are using plain html? Because of using AngularJs or something similar? Otherwise it's better use `ActiveForm` widget with AJAX validation.

Comment: `if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax)` always false because you are not using proper yii ajax call. check before it you will get posted data.

Comment: remove  `if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax)`. then it will work.

Comment: yes, I get the result, but why is it showing on new page?

Comment: @arogachev, I'll use jquery validation. The reason is that the form will be placed on a website that does not support Yii. The backend will be on the separate server.

Comment: because you were not specifying any page in controller action, use redirect().

Comment: What if I just want to return some json and show it on the same page, without redirecting? My ajax success function is not firing.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the solution is to remove action from form:

```
<form id="myform" action="" method="post">
```

js:

```
$("#myform").submit( function(e){
      var form = $(this);
      $.ajax({
            url    : '/megogo/web/index.php?r=form/preorder',
            type   : 'POST',
            data   : form.serialize(),
            success: function (response) 
            {                  
               console.log(response);
            },
            error  : function (e) 
            {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    return false;        
  })
```